# not getting the values passed by the socket.io client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I am stuck at the get-started part of [socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) tutorial, on emitting events. Before that, I did get the **user connected** and **user disconnected** in the console. However, in the emitting part, I don't get any **message** passed by the socket.io client in the console.

This is the code so far:

index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>

  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate if you could guide me through this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a line in your index.js

Instead of:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
```

You should have:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

What's happening is that in the html file, when you submit a chat message, you are emitting it back to to server, who needs to emit it back to all of the other users. Without that io.emit line, all of the other users will not get the message

*edit: Also in your html file, it should look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>

  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
   socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

It wasn't working because you were running your script first which references a jQuery element that doesn't exist yet. If you wanted to keep the body where it was, you would need to wrap the scripts in a $(document).ready function. Also you were forgetting to append the message on incoming chat message sockets.

Comment: Yes, but before, even emitting to the user back, its supposed to show the message in the console, but it isn't. And I even went ahead and added the client side javascript to get the message passed by the server back. But no luck, its not showing the message to the console nor in the browser side.

Comment: Just to clarify, the console logs will show up in your terminal or wherever you are running the index.js, and not in your browser

Comment: Yes. I am running it in the terminal, but it isn't showing in the console neither in the browser. :(

Comment: I found the problem and updated the answer. Basically there was some html shuffling and a missing socket.on call